# I want to show a successful warning post after a file uploaded using React js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I upload the file using React js filepond component. Then I convert an uploaded file to base64 string format. I want to print a green text "successfully" after the `props.values.addendumA = converted` statement in `if (file [0])`. How can I do that?

***React js***

```
<Form className="orange-color ml-2">
  <FilePond
    ref={ref => ref}
    allowFileEncode={true}
    allowMultiple={false}
    oninit={() => console.log("FilePond A has initialised")}
    onupdatefiles={fileItems => {
      let file = fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file);

      let coded = file[0];
      if (file[0]) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = event => {
          console.log(event.target.result);
        };
        let converted = reader.readAsDataURL(coded);

        props.values.addendumA = converted;

        //TODO HERE
        ("Successfully uploaded");
      }
      console.log(props.values.addendumA);
    }}
  />
</Form>
```

Comment: Are you using any styling library? Antd provides a good warning message component.

Comment: I am using react bootstrap.

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap you can use the toasts that are provided by it.
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/toasts/
it is pretty easy to import and use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display a success `toast` using `react-toastify`. It's really simple and handy.
Here's how you can do it. First, run `yarn add react-toastify` or `npm install toastify`.

Then import the package in the component you want to display toast.

```
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
```

```
props.values.addendumA = converted;
    toast.success("Successfully uploaded");
  }
```

Final step is to include the `ToastContainer` in your root component, most probably in your `App.js` file like this. Don't forget to import these packages in the root component  too.

```
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
```

Add this component anywhere in your `return` method.

```
<ToastContainer autoClose={3000} hideProgressBar />
```